# Edit R function within a package

Tags: r

I have the dcemriS4 package, which has some functions I am interested in editing.

Is there some way to make permanent changes to these functions outside of the R environment? I could download the source code directly from sourceforge, and I see the sections that need editing there, but can't find any reference to these functions on my filesystem.

I see that there is a way to re-define the function within an instance of R, but I am going to be using this package a lot, many times from different bash scripts, so I would prefer to just be able to load the package in R without having to 'temporarily' change the function every time via some kind of extra initialization script..

Comment: Create a new package with all the changes in it then load that package at the beginning of the script.

Comment: you can fork https://github.com/cran/dcemriS4 and use `devtools::install_github()` to make your own version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking the repository in git, and creating my own branch. You can then download the modified branch from Git, uninstall the old package by simply removing the folder where it was installed - use `.libPaths()` to find its location - and then use `install.packages('/path/to/newpackage', repos=NULL)`